# IF Button in datagridview is clicked vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I want to click button in datagridview by code.Can you help me?

```
    Dim btn1 As New DataGridViewButtonColumn()
    Data_analysis_confirm.Columns.Add(btn1)
    btn1.HeaderText = "แก้ไข"
    btn1.Text = "เลือก"
    btn1.Name = "btn_edit"
    btn1.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = True
```

I'll try this code and it not work
THIS CODE

```
Private Sub Data_analysis_confirm_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles Data_analysis_confirm.CellClick
    If Data_analysis_confirm.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "แก้ไข" Then
        MsgBox("แก้ไข")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use handle the [CellContentClick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellcontentclick.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) event instead, which fires only when content in a cell is clicked. The [CellClick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event will fire when any part of a cell is clicked.

Additionally your code has an issue where you are comparing the wrong value for the column name (`แก้ไข` instead of the actual name, `btn_edit`).

```
Private Sub Data_analysis_confirm_CellContentClick(sender As System.Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles Data_analysis_confirm.CellContentClick
    If e.RowIndex < 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim grid = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)

    If TypeOf grid.Columns(e.ColumnIndex) Is DataGridViewButtonColumn Then
        If grid.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "btn_edit" Then
            MsgBox("แก้ไข")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```